# A graph with exactly one vertex of degree one contains a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

> A graph $G$ with exactly one vertex of degree one contains a cycle.  Is there any counter example?

I could not find any graph for counterexample.  Please help.

Comment: Have you tried proving there are no counterexamples?

Comment: Are you really posting a screenshot of one sentence?

Comment: Then,is the statement always true ?

Comment: When I wrote,there was an error I could not find.Hence,it is so easy to use screenshot.

Comment: Hint. Can you draw a graph with a cycle and no vertices of degree $1$? Can you add anything to that graph that will help with your question?

Comment: @EthanBolker Are you sure you're reading the question correctly? I don't think that helps.

Comment: @Casteels Rereading, I agree that I may not be reading the question as the OP intended. I think the question as written is genuinely ambiguous. If he clarifies I can delete my hint.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think you interpreted it as "does there exist an example of a graph with a cycle and exactly one vertex of degree one?"  The expected interpretation is "Prove the following: If $G$ is a graph with exactly one vertex of degree one, then it must contain a cycle.   If the statement is false, then provide a counterexample"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Theorem** Any graph with exactly one vertex of degree 1 has a cycle

*Proof*:  Let $G$ be a graph with exactly one vertex of degree one, we will label as $v$.  Without loss of generality, we may assume that every other vertex has degree 2 and that the graph is connected.

(*by deleting edges we only make it harder to form cycles, so if we prove that it must have a cycle in this harder form, then it must have had a cycle before deleting edges as well.  we may assume it is connected since otherwise we can simply focus our attention on the one component that has the vertex of degree one*)

As a vertex with degree one has a neighbor, $G$ has at least 2 vertices.

A connected graph without cycles is one of the many equivalent definitions of a **tree**.  We wish to prove that our graph $G$ is not a tree.

> **Lemma**: A tree, $T$, with $n\geq 2$ vertices has at least two vertices of degree 1 (known as **leaves**).

*Proof of lemma:* The number of vertices of $T$ is $n$ and the number of edges is $n-1$ (seen easily by induction if you haven't before).  By the handshaking lemma, the sum of the degrees is $2(n-1)$.  Since our tree is connected there are no vertices of degree zero.  If we didn't have two or more vertices of degree 1 then we would have $n-1$ vertices of degree at least 2 and the remaining vertex of degree 1 or greater, but that would imply by the handshaking lemma that our number of edges would be greater or equal to $\frac{2(n-1)+1}{2}$ which is a contradiction (we already know that we have $n-1$ edges).  Thus every tree has at least two vertices of degree one.

*Proof that the lemma implies the theorem*:  Since $G$ has exactly one vertex of degree 1, it cannot be a tree by the previous lemma.  Since it is not a tree, it cannot satisfy the definitions for being a tree: in particular it is not a graph that is connected without any cycles.  Since it *is* connected though, that implies that the reason it does not fit that definition for a tree is that it must have a cycle.